Filter records based on enum array column in ActiveRecords Rails
class ModelName < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end

For example, purpose "ModelName" has a column name 'example_column' with type of enum array. Let's consider the enums are "first", "second", "third" and "fourth".
Need help in writing a query for searching records which has as a certain enum in an enum array.
So let say I want to search for all the records which has enum "first".
I have tried using below statement:
ModelName.where(example_column: ['first']).id

This statement will generate below SQL query:
select id from model_name where example_column = '{first}';

This query only fetches records which has only 'first' enum in the enum array. If the enum array contains 'first' and 'second', it won't fetch that record.
I tried using below query,
select id from model_name where example_column::text ilike '%first%'

Is there any better way of doing this in ActiveRecord Rails than above mentioned query?

While enums have their place -- they are not ideal for querying -- especially in this situation. If you are using postgres and a json column to store the array you can use  a json query to match the records. Otherwise pulling the enum column into a join table will make querying straightforward.

The ActiveRecord query interface doesn't actually handle array columns, JSON columns, or any of those other structured data types you probably shouldn't be using. They are not polyglot and quirky as hell across dbs. If you want something it  actually supports use a table the way a relational database was designed to be used.

Thank you for the inputs. I will try to en-cooperate the suggestions.
